# Изменение значения переменной в базовом шаблоне, jinja2

Tags: python, jinja2

Необходимо изменить значение переменной `login_status` в базовом шаблоне, который используется для всех страниц приложения, с помощью python, jinja2. Переменная также имеет значение по умолчанию - "Вход". Если вход в личный кабинет удался, `login_status` приобретает значение "Выход", если нет - "Вход". Но корректно изменение переменной происходит только на одной странице личного кабинета, а на всех остальных страницах продолжает использоваться значение по умолчанию.

Kак исправить такое положение?

base.html:

```
<li class="in">{{login_status | default('Вход')}}</li>
 <form name="form_in" method = 'post' action = '/personal_account'>
       <input type="text"  placeholder="Логин" id="log" name="login"/>
       <input type="password"  placeholder="Пароль" id="pass" name="password"/>
       <input type="submit"/>
 </form>
```

Функция на python:

```
@app.route('/personal_account', methods=['POST'])
def welcome():
    login = request.form['login']
    password = request.form['password']
    login_status = u'Выйти'
    sidebar_login_status = 'out'
    if not validate_user(login, password):
        login_status = u'Войти'
        sidebar_login_status = 'in'
        return u'Неправильный логин!', login_status, sidebar_login_status

    # добавлено после Edit One
    user = User()
    user.id = login
    login_user(user)
    # .......

    data = get_user_data(login)
    return render_template('private.html',
                           data=data,
                           login_status=login_status,
                           sidebar_login_status=sidebar_login_status)
```

**EDIT ONE**

Для сохранения "логинизации" пользователя используется модуль Flask-Login. Класс User() используется как он есть по-умолчанию.

Проблема в том, что юзер то остается залогиненым в течении всей сессии, а мне нужно, чтобы в этом случае менялось значение переменной `login_status` в базовом html шаблоне.

Comment: посмотрите как flask-login устроен https://flask-login.readthedocs.io

Comment: Смотрите Edit One

Comment: @lipton_v почему бы вам в шаблоне просто не проверять `current_user.is_authenticated` вместо использования переменной `login_status`?

Comment: Если у вас уже есть `current_user.is_authenticated`, то используйте это значение, что `login_status` желаемый выставить.

Comment: Если вставить в базовый шаблон проверку на логинезацию, то получается каждый раз при при переходе пользователя на любую страницу сайта, будет производиться проверка? Это не будет являться лишней нагрузкой? Нельзя ли сделать проверку один раз, а затем сохранять статус, пока не произойдет событие нажатия на кнопку выход?

Comment: @lipton_v у вас уже в контексте шаблона есть переменная `current_user` с установленным полем `is_authenticated`. Лишней нагрузкой, хоть и несущественной, является использованием дополнительной переменной `login_status`.

Answer (score 0):

C Flask-Login не знаком, но почему бы не брать значение login_status из сессии:

```
<a href="{{url_for('login')}}"> {{session.get('login_status', 'log in')}} </a>
```

Проверка и смена статуса будyт производится только при вызове специальной функции:

```
from flask import Flask, session, redirect, url_for, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/login')
def login():
    login_status = session.get('login_status', 'log in')
    if login_status == 'log in': session['login_status'] = 'log out'
    elif login_status == 'log out': session['login_status'] = 'log in'
    return redirect(url_for('index'))

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.secret_key = '123'
    app.run(debug=True)
```